# New Q&A Site Request

Tags: discussion

Where and how do I request for a new category/Q&A site?

What are the qualifications/requirements (if any have been set)?

Comment: First, visit [area51.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request a new site at area51.stackexchange.com. The FAQ explains how the process works.

Comment: Wow! You just posted an answer after 3 hours after the question was closed.

Comment: Hmm. Is suspect there is a bug in the iOS app. Will submit a report.